# How do I increase the swap size on a xen guest machine using xm?

Tags: swap, xen

I'm attempting to increase the amount of swap on a xen guest machine.  At first I thought it'd be similar to increasing the hard drive space, which I do like this:

```
cd /srv/xen/domains/$host/
xm shutdown $host
cp disk.img disk.img.backup
dd if=/dev/zero of=ZeroContentFile bs=1024 count=$numberofextrabytes
cat ZeroContentFile >> disk.img
rm ZeroContentFile
resize2fs -f disk.img
fsck.ext3 disk.img
xm create $host.cfg
```

I've tried doing the same thing, but replacing disk.img with swap.img.  This works fine up until the point I do the `resizefs -f swap.img`, I get:

```
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open swap.img
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

To be honest, I never expected this command to work exactly the same for swap as it did for ext3.  However, if I leave it out, then the guest just ends up with the same amount of swap as it had before.
What's the equivalent command I need to run to get the whole of swap.img recognised as swap space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the EXT tools because swap is not an EXT file-system. Resize the disk image from the host and then three simple steps in the guest typically:

```
swapoff
mkswap /dev/[swapdevice]
swapon
```

Which unloads the swap partition, formats it and then activates it again. `[swapdevice]` can be determined from `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: How do I know what [swapdevice] is meant to be?
I also don't understand why I can increase the size of the ext3 partition fully on the host, but for the swap partition I need to log into the guest.  Seems a bit inconsistent.  Is there some fundamental difference between ext3 and swap which I don't understand?

Comment: For the record, this does work and the default [swapdevice] seems to be `xvda1` (atleast for my setup).
I still don't understand why such a difference between ext3 and swap, but atleast it works.

Comment: Updated my answer